# Formulating constraints with two boolean variables

Tags: optimization, boolean, or-tools, cp-sat

I was trying to figure our how can I formulate a constraint with which includes 2 boolean variables.

my basic constrains look something line this.

```
# x + const_a <= const_b 

model.Add(x + const_a <= const_b).OnlyEnforceIf(bool_1)
```

but I want to add another boolean variable and my equation looks like:

```
# x + const_a * bool_2 + const_a * (1 - bool_2) <= const_b

model.Add(x + const_a * bool_2 (?) + const_a(1 - bool_2)(?)  <= const_b).OnlyEnforceIf([bool_1, bool_2]) 
# is this how it should be approached?
```

and this is also confusing me when I think of boolean varaibles implementation as an implication.
How can I formulate this kind of contraints? Do I need to have two separate constraints for 2 different boolean varaibles or it can be done in single constraint?

Comment: Your equation can be simplified without book_2. Is this what you want ?

Comment: No, I want to incorporate bool_2 in my equation.

Comment: I want to transform it to something like (x + a(bool_2) + b(1 - bool_2) <= c).OnlyEnforceIf(bool_1)
And I am not sure how to do that. Also, will the OnlyEnforceIf([bool_1, bool_2]) is going to be required or not, that also I am not sure about

Comment: x + (a -b) * bool2 + b <= c ?

Comment: You can write with bigM formulation. I find it less readable. But it will be presolved into enforcement literals.